# MVC action not being called from grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

I have an MVC3 app that uses a Telerik grid. I have the following action:

```
public ActionResult FileDownload(string id)
```

On my grid, I have a ClientTemplate that renders a small box. when the user clicks the box, I want the action to be called. Heres my grid (just one line of it for brevity):

```
columns.Bound(c => c.DocID).ClientTemplate("<div><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\"  
    class=\"link-button-small\" onclick=\"javascript:downloadFile(<#= DocID #>)\">...</a> 
</div>");
```

This is my javascript:

```
function downloadFile(docId) {
    var url = "@(Url.Content("~/OrderDetails/FileDownload/"))" + docId;
    $('#downloadFrame').attr('src',url); //dumping some data to an iFrame
}
```

The javascript function is called just fine, but my Action is never executed. I can call my action using other methods like using the ClientEvents on the Telerik grid, so my Action is fine. Does anyone know why my Action isnt called when using a Client Template? Thanks

Comment: What does the rendered HTML for the column look like?

Comment: <td><div><a onclick="downloadFile(1639)" class="link-button-small" href="javascript:">...</a> 5033799_Capture.PNG</div></td>

Comment: OK. Next question: what is the value of `url` in your js function? If it's not correct, you can use `Url.Action( "...action...", "...controller..." )` instead.

Comment: I agree with @Nicholas. Its likely that your link isnt directed correctly. Try the above for a better approach. This will take into account the full structure of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
columns.Bound(c => c.DocID).ClientTemplate("<div><a href='javascript:' class='link-button-small' onclick='downloadFile(<#= DocID #>)'>...</a></div>");
```

Based upon this [Telerik Forum post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/calling-javascript-method-with-parameters-in-clienttemplate-not-working.aspx).

There may be an issue with the escape sequence.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this appears to be a fix if the javascript isnt being called. My javascript is being called fine, but the action the javascript is trying to call on the server is never being fired.

Comment: If you place an alert(url) between var url and $('#downloadFrame') it captures the correct url?